# Python selenium automation Linkedin post

Tags: python, selenium

I want to try to automate posting on LinkedIn with selenium. My code works fine until I arrive to the post section. I tried many options x_path, class_name but I get stuck. The message is not written.

I am not sure if I have to use send_keys. I have seen a tuto on youtube similar but with Facebook. Unfortunately, I couldn't adapt it on Linkedin.

If someone has got an idea. I am a complete beginner with selenium and I have some basis of python

Thx

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/')

#enter mail
time.sleep(1)
email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_key"]')
email_box.send_keys('email')

#enter password
time.sleep(1)
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_password"]')
password.send_keys('password')

#checkbox I accept

searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main- 
content"]/section[1]/div[2]/form/button')
searchButton.click()

#checkbox taf no

#searchBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember48"]')
#searchBox.click()

#chekbox post
box_post = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/button')
box_post.click()
time.sleep(2)

#post boite check
#post_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember404"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
#post_area.click()

#add post 

postarea = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember395"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/p')
postarea.click()
time.sleep(2)
activepostarea=driver.switch_to_active_element()
postarea.send_keys("La nouvelle mise à jour")
#activepostarea=driver.switch_to_active_element()
#activepostarea("La nouvelle mise à jour")

#envoyer le post
time.sleep(2)

button_post = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember705"]')
button_post.click()
```

Comment: remove your password, you shouldn't put that out there publicly

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
postarea = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ql-editor.ql-blank")
postarea.send_keys("test")
```

Post:

[image]

Comment: Wow it worked perfectly, thanks. Now i have an issue with post button to post the message. As before, I tried x_path (no success), class_name (no success), by_id (no success) . For the id, I have "ember + number", it seems that the number changes with every new post??? What did you try to send the post?

Comment: I didn’t actually post it because I don’t want to post messages on my LinkedIn account. Maybe accept this answer since it resolved your initial question and ask a new one and someone can help you out.

Comment: try this xpath: `//div[@class='share-box_actions']//span[@class='artdeco-button__text']`

Comment: or this: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("share-actions__primary-action")`

Comment: ,I have just tried your first idea xpath and it worked perfectly. thank you. When I tried to copy xpath element, i didn't get the same path. Did you get it by a right click copy or did you write it based on html code ?

Comment: I write custom x-paths.  The problem with right clicking the element and copying the xPath is it copies the FULL path.  It is very brittle that way.  What I do is open Chrome, hit F12, then click down in the HTML and click ctrl-F.  That opens up a find window.  You can then test different x-paths or whatever you want, and it tells you how many elements are found on that page.  1 of 1 is what you are looking for, if you want a single element.  If you see 1 of 2 or 1 of (whatever other number) you know you need to narrow it down even more in your xpath

Comment: please accept/upvote the answer if it solved your issue